# JPA Hibernate Help!

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, netbeans-6.9

I have just studied about JPA.
And I had created a simple program which return the query "SELECT ...".
Unfortunately, I always get an exception like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to application.Model
   at application.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

I can't understand why, yet I tried using String.valueOf(...) to the line and returns the same exception.

All of the codes are present [here](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/42001-jpa-help.html#post195648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
List<Model> models = query.getResultList();
```

You can try -

```
List<Model> models = entityManager.createQuery("from Model",Model.class).getResultList();
```

I don't see any purpose for using native query here.

Comment: I see... But I have solve the problem. I had used TopLink instead of Hibernate.